# How can I put a withdrawing or donating group in an aromatic ring in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, mhchem

I need to put an undetermined electron withdrawing or donating group in an organic molecule (an aromatic ring), using arrows instead of lines as bonds, but with the barbs just in the middle.
This is an example, with arrows in red and blue:
[image]

This is possible in chemfig to change the bond configuration from a line to an arrow?

My best shot was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,->]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]HO))--)} \quad
\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,<-]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]H\charge{90=\:,-90=\:}{O}))--)}

\end{document}
```

But seems quite different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the bond in half.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}    
    \chemfig{**6(-(-[,0.5,,,blue,->]-[,0.5,,,blue]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]HO))--)} \quad
    \chemfig{**6(-(-[,0.5,,,red]-[,0.5,,,red,<-]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]H\charge{90=\:,-90=\:}{O}))--)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

you can change arrow style using TIKZ `blue,-stealth]` and `red,stealth-]` commands in bond options

Comment: Thanks a Lot!!!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's at least a route you can follow. Code's result:

[image]

A few comments:

- `chemfig` is built on `tikz`, so you can apply tikz concepts one way or the other (search the chemfig manual)
- ring 1 shows a simple recoloring of the whole line including the arrow tip in `red`
- ring 2 uses some `tikz decoration`, see ch. 12.3; it requires `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing` and the "clumsy" options `... ->,decorate,decoration=snake]G)`
- ring 3 uses a self-defined style, see the `\tikzset` statement in the beginning; see ch. 12.7 chemfig, and ch. 50.6 tikz manual; for illustration purposes I used two colors; you should be able to replace the `X` by an arrow tip // This is where tikzlibrary `decorations.markings` is required // it's a bit like with LISP, you can get lost easily in required braces ...
- ring 4 is unchanged, for reference, for the opposite arrow direction
- ring 5 proves the self-defined style `arr` works there, too

One minor problem remains for ring 5: the `red X` is set halfways of the related path; as you can see, the starting- or end-point must be at or close to the inner circle. Worst case you need to have a `second arr-style` defined, depending on the arrows direction.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,% for the snake line
                decorations.markings}% for the "shifted" arrow tip


\begin{document}

% from chemfig manual ch. 12.7
%\tikzset{nbond/.style args={#1}{%
%   draw=none,%
%   decoration={%
%       markings,%
%       mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (CFstart@) at (0,0);},
%       mark=at position 1 with 
%       {%
%           \foreach\CF_i in{0,1,...,\number\numexpr#1-1}{%
%           \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_nbondcoeff{\CF_i-0.5*(#1-1)}%
%           \draw ([yshift=\CF_nbondcoeff\CF_doublesep]CFstart@)--(0,\CF_nbondcoeff\CF_doublesep);
%           }%
%       }
%   },
%   postaction={decorate}
%   }
%}

\tikzset{
    arr/.style={green!40!black,
    decoration={
        markings,% see ch. 50.6 in the tikz-manual
        mark=at position 0.5
        with
        {
            \node [red] {X};
%           \draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);
%           \draw (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);
        }
    },
    postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,->,red]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]HO))--)} \quad

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,->,decorate,decoration=snake]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]HO))--)} \quad

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,->,arr]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]HO))--)} \quad

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,<-]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]H\charge{90=\:,-90=\:}{O}))--)} \quad

\chemfig{**6(-(-[,,,,<-,arr]G)---(-C(=[:30]\charge{90=\:,-30=\:}{O})(-[:150]H\charge{90=\:,-90=\:}{O}))--)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much MS-SPO!!!